# How do I make a div that is the width of the entire screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If a div A is contained inside another div (B) that is 500px wide, how can div A still be the width of the entire screen? I want to "break out" of that 500px div.

Comment: Get the `window` width and set the css width with js. As long as your item is positioned absolute with high zindex it should work just fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your question, you could use `position:absolute` in div A. It will find the nearest positioned parent (a parent that has either fixed, absolute or relative position). But you need to have the nearest positioned element have 100% width and is positioned snug to the left.

[here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BNWfe/1/) using body

```
<body>
    <div id="b">
        <div id="a">test</div>
    </div>
</body>

body{
    position:relative;
}

#b{
    width:500px;
}

#a{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: In your fiddle it's `.body` instead of `body`

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: absolute` on the child div and keep the parent on `position: static`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to make div A's position: absolute;

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want it to look like. Using the css:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

will make the div be larger than the containing div but hidden behind it,

otherwise, if you want it to be shown on top of the containing div you could use the 'position' css like the other answers given.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class or id to your div tag. This css will work for both

```
#yourdivid .yourdivclass {
     position:absolute;
     left:0;
     right:0;
     overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/HRT2M/

```
.b
{
Position:fixed;
}
```

on div b should get it working for you

Martyn

Answer (score 0):

You can use min-width to force the div B to certain width -

```
<div id="a" style="width:500px;display:block;">
  <div id="b" style="min-width:960px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also use javascript to set its width -

```
<script style="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById ("b").style.width = window.screen.width;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="b" style="width:500px;">
   <div id="a" style="width:100%; position:absolute; overflow:hidden;"><div/>
</div>
```

This works.